# Управление файлами для загрузки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring

Есть input type file multiple. Как мне реализовать удаление прикрепленного файла при нажатии, например на крестик. Такая возможность есть вконтакте, когда я прикрепляю несколько файлов, но не отправляю, я могу открепить один или несколько, нажав на крестик.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно будет потом отправить файлы на сервер.

Есть мысль загружать файлы во временный каталог сразу после добавления и при отмене или отправке удалять из временной директории и загружать в статическую. Но правильно ли так делать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943605/remove-a-filelist-item-from-a-multiple-inputfile

Answer (score 0):

В общем `fileList` только `readonly`.
Нужно делать свое временное хранилище, при визуальном удалении файла обновлять свое хранилище и перезаписывать `input[type="file"].files`

Это **очень краткий** ответ, но реализовать возможно